# Drag N Drop object on top of each other in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Drag and drop items from 1 panel to another one by one. Every item I move from panel1 to panel2 should always appear on top of previous item in panel2

I am trying to drag and drop object from one panel to another. I am able to successfully move 1 object from panel1 and drop in panel2. But when I select the 2nd object in panel1, the first one comes back.

I want to able to drag and drop all objects from panel 1, one-by-one in panel 2. On drop the items should be stack one on top of the other.

I have the following code implementing drag:

```
public class Drag : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public string playArea = "PlayArea";
    public string playerHand = "PlayerHand";

    static public GameObject itemBeingDragged;
    public Vector3 startPosition;

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = eventData.pointerDrag;
        itemBeingDragged.transform.SetAsLastSibling();
        startPosition = itemBeingDragged.transform.position;
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged.transform.position = eventData.position;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.pointerEnter !=null && eventData.pointerEnter.transform.name == playArea)
        {
            itemBeingDragged.transform.position = eventData.position;
        }
        else
        {
            itemBeingDragged.transform.position = startPosition;

        }
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update 
    void Start()
    {
        
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }    
}
```

I believe the issue with items coming back from panel 2 into panel1 when I select the 2nd item is because of the line itemBeingDragged.transform.SetAsLastSibling()" in the OnBeginDrag method.

When I remove this line, I am able to take all items 1 by 1 from panel1 and leave  in panel2, however I am not able to always stack the item onto the previous item. Some items go behind and some item stay on top.

Any helps would be highly appreciated.

Video of issue: [Drag and drop items from 1 panel to another one by one. Every item I move from panel1 to panel2 should always appear on top of previous item in panel2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrrLM.gif)

Comment: Probably related to siblings coupled with some UI layout component. Try additionally to move/parent them between the two hierarchies of the corresponding panels.

Comment: @Nikaas I added the line on the OnEndDrag method: itemBeingDragged.transform.SetParent(eventData.pointerEnter.transform);

This unfortunately now results in the item coming back instantly. As soon as i drop the item in panel2, it instantly comes back to panel 1

Comment: Try to remove the `else` block from the dragEnd and see what happens. If it happens again then its the ui layout,

Comment: The issue was with the update method. It had a line that was setting the parent to a hardcoded value. I am very new to unity dev, and didn't realize this was the issue when i was following the youtube tutorial. Fixing that now works as expected.

Just working on another issue where I am not able to drop directly on another object.I can drop beside it, but not on top of another object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very silly, but there was an update method on the itemBeingDragged's GameObject where I had written the code to set the parent. The update method in Unity dev gets called continuously, which means any code written in the update method  to set a static variable will always overwrite any other changes you make somewhere else.